# Get like statistics of all pages

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Hi  want to get all likes of my blog pages and present the most liked articles to my visitors!

I already know how to do that for a single article ie. URL.

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.stackoverflow.com%2F%27&format=json

1) I am interested is there a way to get likes of ALL PAGES with a single query?
2) If I try to get likes of my pages (one by one with method described above)  will Facebook block my queries?